# How to achieve smooth transitions between operational modes in the bidirectional buck-boost dc-dc converter?

Tags: power-electronics, control, pid-controller

I have below given DC-DC converter

[image]

Until this moment I have used this converter for current control either in the buck or in the boost mode in the indicated current flow direction. The control algorithm I have implemented in the DSP enables harmonic transition between the buck and boost mode and vice versa via following control structure:

[image]

It is worthwhile to say that this control structure is fully functional. In the time being I would like to extend the existing control structure in such a manner enabling harmonic transition into the current control also in opposite direction. So I have been thinking about how to modify the splitter block internals. The idea which I have is to apply following modification:

[image]

Before I will test this idea I would like to know another opinion. Thanks in advance for any remarks.

**EDIT**:

- \$d_u\$ is a duty cycle for the upper transistor in the left half bridge
- \$d_v\$ is a duty cycle for the upper transistor in the right half bridge
- \$d_u\$, \$d_v\$ are the inputs for a pwm generator peripheral in the dsp
- the transistors in one half bridge are switched in complementary mode
- the pwm signal routing to the individual transistors is achieved via output mask of the pwm peripheral which effectively sets the converter topology

Comment: The circuit is identical in either direction of current so what should be the problem?

Comment: @Andyaka thank you for your reaction. Does it mean that you find my idea viable?

Comment: No, I didn't look at your idea. I asked you what you saw the problem to be.

Comment: I am not sure whether the control structure extension I have proposed above can't produce some unwelcome current transients due to the converter topology changes.

Comment: The notation here is unfamiliar. Could you please describe things in better detail? Example: what is du, dv? Do we assume the transistors are driven complementary (synchronous / half-bridge)? Does the "splitter" block produce a control value or a pulse signal? If not, is there an implied PWM generator between these two drawings? What role does the function shown serve in the greater system, is this a current mode controller or something? (A typical embodiment would suffice, like an adjustable voltage converter, even if you're doing something more complex.)

Comment: If I assume a most likely answer to all these, the most likely question that arises is: if using bootstrap transistor drivers, how will you ensure 100% duty in the respective modes? You may want to limit the outputs somewhat below 1.0, or have another solution for this. If this is strictly an abstract control scheme, I suppose it doesn't matter, but this is also an example where abstraction fails, i.e., implementation details can cause push-back on the control scheme.

Comment: (I provide this as example to prompt either further detail be added, or thought on the subject. If this turns out to be an answer, then I'll gladly convert this/these comments accordingly.)

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for your reaction. I have just attempted to append the missing information.